# How to get list items without for each in MVC controller

Tags: c#, foreach, asp.net-mvc-5

I need to access items from a list which is i am accessing with the following code

```cs
foreach (var reportval in reportresponse)
{
    foreach (var valitem in reportval.Comparison)
    {
        var responsemodel = new ReportResponseModel();
        responsemodel.StudentVariable = valitem.StudentVariable;
        responsemodel.Lighter = valitem.Lighter;
        responsemodel.Matched = valitem.Matched;
        responsemodel.Stronger = valitem.Stronger;
        reportResponseModel.Add(responsemodel);                            
    }
};
```

I tried the following code to exit the loop without retiterting the first loop. But its not working.

```cs
if (reportresponse.Count == reportResponseModel.Count) { break; };
```

also i tried the following way to access the inner list from the first loop but its not accessible here

```cs
foreach (var reportval in reportresponse.Comparison)
```

Can someone please help on this?

Comment: Wrap the code in a `public List<ReportResponseModel> MyMethod() { ...}` and use `if (reportresponse.Count == reportResponseModel.Count) { return reportResponseModel; }; to exit the function and return the collection

Comment: Its already wrapped in the following method

internal List<ReportResponseModel> MapToViewModel(List<ReportResponse> reportresponse)
        {
           
                
            
        }

Comment: Then adding `if (reportresponse.Count == reportResponseModel.Count) { return reportResponseModel; };` after  `reportResponseModel.Add(responsemodel);` should work fine (although its not clear what would the purpose of your `if` statement is)

Comment: @StephenMuecke if statement purpose is to exit from the loop as it was executing double the number of records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the code with the following changes.

```
if (reportresponse.Count == reportResponseModel.Count) 
{ return reportResponseModel; };
```

after

```
reportResponseModel.Add(responsemodel);
```

Thanks @Stephen Muecke !!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try like this

```
foreach (var reportval in reportresponse.Comparison)
{

       // var responsemodel = new ReportResponseModel();
        responsemodel.StudentVariable = valitem.StudentVariable;
        responsemodel.Lighter = reportval .Lighter;
        responsemodel.Matched = reportval .Matched;
        responsemodel.Stronger = reportval .Stronger;
        //reportResponseModel.Add(responsemodel);                            
    }
};
```

Comment: Yes and it says The name "responsemodel" does not exist in this context.

Comment: i want to ask you one thing... you are iteration in a list called reportresponse and then you are creating an object of ReportResponseModel ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Linq's `SelectMany`?

You can do something like

```
var reportResponseModel = reportresponse.SelectMany(r => r.Comparison, (r, c) =>
    new ReportResponseModel
    {
        StudentVariable = c.StudentVariable,
        Lighter = c.Lighter,
        Matched = c.Matched,
        Stronger = c.Stronger
    });
```

Then you can apply additional filtering like with `.Where` or `.Take` to have only needed count of items.